# Macro which defines the function

Tags: c++, if-statement, macros

I use the following macro to generate function code

```
#define EXTRACT_INSTRUCTION32_FIELD(insName,fieldName,fieldOffset) \
    insName##Instruction::##fieldName val; \
    val = static_cast<##insName##Instruction::##fieldName##>((hexIstruction & ##insName##Mask_##fieldName) >> fieldOffset); \
    return val
```

But I don`t want to use `return val` always.Also I don`t want to split this macro to be 2 macros.How can I do that?Thought about to use some `isRet`

```
 #define EXTRACT_INSTRUCTION32_FIELD(insName,fieldName,fieldOffset,isRet) \
        insName##Instruction::##fieldName val; \
        val = static_cast<##insName##Instruction::##fieldName##>((hexIstruction & ##insName##Mask_##fieldName) >> fieldOffset); \
        if (##isRet)\
        return val
```

I don`t like that solution ,it decreases the performance - any advises hot to do that?

Comment: You're overusing the `##` operator, it's not needed in most places you use it. I'm not even sure it's "legal" to use it in some places you do.

Comment: Why are you using `##isRet`, when you are not actually concatenating with any other identifier? You can simply use `isRet`. Similarly, you can use `fieldName` instead of `##fieldName` for 2 of the total 3 usages.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but I bet the same result could be achieved by using **inline** functions and pointers, just in more elegant and readable way.

Comment: Why not two macros? The one that returns can be defined in terms of the one that doesn't.

Comment: can you say exactly what ## are not needed?

Comment: The `##` operator is needed only when creating an identifier from a macro argument and another identifier (e.g. `insName##Instruction`). It's _not_ needed when putting a macro argument next to a non-identifier character (you can e.g. use `::fieldName` without the operator).

Comment: You will find it MUCH easier to debug this if you use (inline) functions rather than macros. The compiler will most likely generate the same code anyways. You may need a macro to do your "paste this text with that text", but make that generate a call to a function, and let the work happen in a function. (And no, you can't conditionally return something in a function that doesn't regularly return something)

Comment: @MatsPetersson - I used this way to be able to generate "similar" code for different instructions.I don`t see how inline helps me - give an example pls

Comment: It helps because when it's not working, you can step through the code in a function, but you can't step through a macro [other than as assembler instructions] because the debugger takes it as "one line". But no, it won't solve your problem if "I want to return something sometimes, and other times not". You will have to solve that with two different macros, or something like that.

Comment: @MatsPetersson - 10x.But I still can`t understand how inline function helps me with such kind of code genration

Comment: Now I've lost you. Do you mean function?

Comment: sorry - please see the updated comment

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to go with the more C++ correct method of using an inline function or template, something along the lines of:

```
template <class T, U, V>
U extractInstruction32Field(T insName, U fieldName, V fieldOffset, W hexInstruction, bool isRet = false)
{
    U retval;
    retval = static_cast<U>((hexInstruction& insName::fieldName) >> fieldOffset);
    if isRet    {   return retval;  }
}
```

Note the `isRet` boolean defaults to false so only if you choose to use it will a value be returned.
Without knowing what your mask (`##Mask_`) value is the above is purely exemplary and I should not think it works , but it should point you down a new avenue of approach.
This kind of approach will allow for type safety and decent error checking, where a define doesn't quite play as nicely.

Comment: +1 OP presumably also wants to get rid of the `U retval` in your solution.

Comment: Yakov, could you clarify your requirements for returns/non-returns? (ie.what conditions do you require returns and no returns under?)  Cheers:)